# WGSL get different results even using the same data

Tags: wgpu-rs, wgsl

I am new to WGSL. I am following the tuorial of [wgpu](https://sotrh.github.io/learn-wgpu/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/#using-a-pipeline) to write my first traingle.

The correct shader is like this

```
// Vertex shader

struct VertexOutput {
    @builtin(position) clip_position: vec4<f32>,
    @location(0) position: vec2<f32>,
};

@vertex
fn vs_main(
    @builtin(vertex_index) in_vertex_index: u32,
) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;
    let x = f32(1 - i32(in_vertex_index)) * 0.5;
    let y = f32(i32(in_vertex_index & 1u) * 2 - 1) * 0.5;
    out.position = vec2<f32>(x, y);
    out.clip_position = vec4<f32>(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);
    return out;
}

// Fragment shader

@fragment
fn fs_main(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    return vec4<f32>(in.position, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

The rendered result:
[image]

Since `out.position` is the same as first two elements of `out.clip_position`, I think I can change the fragment shader like this

```
- return vec4<f32>(in.position, 0.5, 1.0);
+ return vec4<f32>(in.clip_position.xy, 0.5, 1.0);
```

But this will give me a wrong result
[image]

Skeleton code can be found [here](https://github.com/sotrh/learn-wgpu/tree/master/code/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `clip_position` uses [`@builtin(position)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#position-builtin-value).

Which means

> An output value (x,y,z,w) [will](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#behavioral-requirements) map to (x/w, y/w, z/w) in WebGPU [normalized device coordinates](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#ndc).

You can easily verify the desired behaviour using the shader below:

```
// Vertex shader

struct VertexOutput {
    @builtin(position) clip_position: vec4<f32>,
    @location(0) position: vec2<f32>,
    @location(1) clip_position_raw: vec4<f32>,
};

@vertex
fn vs_main(
    @builtin(vertex_index) in_vertex_index: u32,
) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;
    let x = f32(1 - i32(in_vertex_index)) * 0.5;
    let y = f32(i32(in_vertex_index & 1u) * 2 - 1) * 0.5;
    out.position = vec2<f32>(x, y);
    out.clip_position = vec4<f32>(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);
    out.clip_position_raw = vec4<f32>(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);
    return out;
}

// Fragment shader

@fragment
fn fs_main(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    return vec4<f32>(in.clip_position_raw.xy, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```